# Problems with ITERATOR in priority_queue

Tags: c++, iterator, priority-queue

I have a C++ problem.
I'm working with CodeBlocks, and I'm declaring: `#include < queue >`
to use a `priority_queue` like that:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<int>,Lower> p;
```

where Lower is defined:

```
struct Lower{
   bool operator<<(priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<int>,Menor> p1, priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<int>,Menor> p2){ 
     return p1.second<p2.second;
   }
}
```

And, when I'm trying to iterate over p, declaring an iterator:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<int>,Menor>::iterator it;
```

It returns this error:

```
error: 'iterator' is not a member of 'std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int> >'
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks.

Comment: If you're hoping to get a sequence sorted on priority you can squelch that idea right now. A priority queue from the standard library is little more than a container adapter wrapped around a random access container (i.e. a deque, a vector) that is used for storage of a min-**heap**. and the resulting iteration would *not* be priority sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *not* iterate over a `std::priority_queue` as this functionality is not provided by its interface.

If you need to be able to iterate over the elements then maybe `std::priority_queue` is not the right choice of container.

If you want a sorted container that you can iterate over, then perhaps you could use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead?

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> s;
s.emplace(20, 2);
s.emplace(10, 2);

// Iterate over pairs in sorted order.
for (auto& pair : s) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or if you need contiguous data allocation then maybe use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) together with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
v.emplace_back(20, 2);
v.emplace_back(10, 2);

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v)); // Sort elements.

// Iterate over pairs...
for (auto& pair : s) {
    /* ... */
}
```